# Replace folder with another one

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want my URL:

```
www.example.org/I/file.php
```

`I` is a fake folder, to be like

```
www.example.org/k/file.php
```

`k` is real folder.

I want for example if the user type `anyfolder` in place of `K` website work for him and another thing is that I want when someone type fake folder I don't want him to be redirected to the real folder `k`.

I want some one to guide me and I will do everything by my self.

By the way does this work with `.htaccess` or PHP or what?

Comment: bismilah is an islamic word

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)\.php$ /k/$1.php [L]
```